# searching for word and unknown number in bash

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search my files that contains a word followed by an unknown number ie

```
grep -Ro "findme" "[0-9]" *
```

but it only returns documents with the word 'findme' in I thought adding brackets around the number meant a range? also it's not a single number ie it could contain a string of 6 ie

```
findme 123456
```

Comment: Put the whole pattern in *one* argument (and use `+` for ‘one or more’): `grep -Ro "findme [0-9]\+" *` Next time read `man grep` first.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your expected match?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`grep -REo "\bfindme [0-9]{1,6}\b"`

{1,6} specifies a range of 1 to 6 digits

Matches Strings of the form:

```
findme <space> <Numbers in range of 1 - 6 digits>
```